# Отладка контейнеров Docker проекта PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

У меня есть Python проект на Django. До того как столкнуться с докером для отладки я использовал удаленный отладчик через SSH, что позволяло мне оперативно изменять файлы на удаленном сервере и тут же видеть эти изменения на страницах (правки как бэкенда так и шаблонов html). Сейчас я хочу научиться строить докеризированные приложения, используя тот же PyCharm. Я настроил интерпретатор через встроенные средства IDE для работы с Python внутри контейнеров, но я не понимаю как оперативно работать с файлами проекта. Например я отследил, что внутри контейнера файлы проекта помещаются в /opt/app и примонтировал рабочую директорию Windows C:***\app к ней, надеясь на то, что при изменении их контейнер будет работать с моими файлами, но оказалось не так. Есть какой-то правильный способ работать напрямую с файлами контейнера через IDE, например через тот же SSH на стороне контейнера (в гугле выяснил что такой подход неверный, но никто не предлагает альтернативу)?

Comment: Через docker-compose.yml опишите ваше сервис. Там подмонтируйте вашу папку в контейнер, возможно понадобится еще провести другие настройки. Это достаточно тривиальная задача и такой подход широко используется в разработке. Как именно это сделать я думаю информации более чем достаточно. Погуглите а тему докер в разработке.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, отпишусь что вышло

Comment: С docker-compose получилось войти в отладку, только меня смущает то что при запуске контейнеров через IDE они буду иметь префикс с названием локального проекта (когда в гите одно название, а папка на компе по другому называется), в этом случае пишет что "извините сервис с таким именем уже запущен" или что-то в этом роде. В любом случае рабочий подход, спасибо!